# Using checkboxGroupInput to show only certain bars on a plot Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

I am using a multi-file setup so I have both ui.r and server.r files. I am using the dataset below (small sample) which looks at UFO sightings in different states/provinces in U.S./Canada in 2016.

```
        Date        Time    AM.PM   Country       City      State   Shape
1   12/21/2016    7:15:00   PM       USA        Waynesboro  VA     Sphere
2   12/21/2016    12:00:00  AM       USA        Louisville  KY     Unknown
3   12/20/2016    10:30:00  PM       USA        Santa Rosa  CA     Sphere
4   12/20/2016    7:00:00   PM       USA        Fresno      CA     Circle
5   12/19/2016    9:53:00   PM       USA        Reymert     AZ     Circle
6   1/11/2016     8:15:00   PM      CANADA     Mississauga  ON     Circle
```

In my app so far, I have created a main panel which displays a bar graph that has all of the different Shapes observed in the "Shape" column on the x-axis and the number of observations on the y-axis. I have a widget on the side which allows the user to select if they want to look at U.S. or Canada data and the plot will change accordingly. What I want to do now is use checkboxGroupInput to allow the user to filter out the shapes that they want to see on the plot's x-axis. I wrote the function in my UI file with all of the possible shapes as seen below. Now I am stuck on how to make it so all of the boxes are selected when the app first launches (without listing every possibility again). On top of this, I am not sure how to add this functionality into the server file so that it will automatically update the plot depending on what shapes the user wants to filter. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

UI File:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Exploring UFO Sightings"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Country",
                        "Country to Display:",
                        choices = list("USA" = 'USA',
                                       "Canada" = 'CANADA'),
                        ),
            checkboxGroupInput("type",
                               "Select Desired Shapes Observed:",
                               choices = list("Changing" = 'Changing',
                                              "Chevron" = 'Chevron',
                                              "Cigar" = 'Cigar',
                                              "Circle" = 'Circle',
                                              "Cone" = 'Cone',
                                              "Cross" = 'Cross',
                                              "Cylinder" = 'Cylinder',
                                              "Diamond" = 'Diamond',
                                              "Disk" = 'Disk',
                                              "Egg" = 'Egg',
                                              "Fireball" = 'Fireball',
                                              "Flash" = 'Flash',
                                              "Formation" = 'Formation',
                                              "Light" = 'Light',
                                              "Other" = 'Other',
                                              "Oval" = 'Oval',
                                              "Rectangle" = 'Rectangle',
                                              "Sphere" = 'Sphere',
                                              "Teardrop" = 'Teardrop',
                                              "Triangle" = 'Triangle',
                                              "Unknown" = 'Unknown'),
                                    selected = c(#Not sure how to select all)
                               ),
        ),
        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("ufoPlot")
        )
    )
))
```

Server File:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$ufoPlot <- renderPlot({
        
        ufo_data_filter <- filter(ufo_data, Country == input$Country)
        ggplot(data = ufo_data_filter) +
            geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Shape))+
            labs(
                title = "Number of Different Shaped UFO Observations",
                x = "Shape of UFO Sighted",
                y = "Number of Observations in 2016"
            )
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote your code to a single syntax but you can adapt it to ui/server form.
First, you don't have to write every single choice if this is available on the data. The `selected` argument in `checkboxGroupInput` can repeat the choices so that each one of them is selected on launch.

For the plot, you just have to add an extra filter for the `Shape` column. Since this can be a multiple selection, the `%in%` operator works for a vector of values.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Exploring UFO Sightings"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Country",
                  "Country to Display:",
                  choices = list("USA" = 'USA',
                                 "Canada" = 'CANADA')),
      checkboxGroupInput("type",
                         "Select Desired Shapes Observed:",
                         choices = unique(ufo_data$Shape),
                         selected = unique(ufo_data$Shape))),
      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("ufoPlot")
      )
    )
  )
  


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
   output$ufoPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    ufo_data_filter <- filter(ufo_data, Country == input$Country & Shape %in% input$type)
    ggplot(data = ufo_data_filter) +
      geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Shape))+
      labs(
        title = "Number of Different Shaped UFO Observations",
        x = "Shape of UFO Sighted",
        y = "Number of Observations in 2016"
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! Thank you so much, I was overcomplicating it in my head.